# Incoming TCP/IP Connections stuck in SYN_RECEIVED state

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I am running a 3rd party product, on Windows 2008 Server, which listens for Incoming connections on port 56600/tcp. The incoming connections are from devices which are trying to report any errors that they may have. These devices are on a (different) 3rd party run network, and port 56600 is enabled between my company's network and the 3rd party network in both directions.

Some devices are able to report their errors on port 56000, but the majority of devices' incoming connections get stuck in the SYN_RECEIVED state and never get properly ESTABLISHED, and so are unable to report errors.

Where should I look to diagnose and correct the problem?

Comment: 1. This isn't a network-programming question. It probably belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. 2. SYN_RECEIVED means that the server received a TCP SYN, responsed with a SYN/ACK, and is now waiting for the remote device to send an ACK to finally establish the connection. It's that last ACK that's not getting through.

Comment: I know what it means, I am trying to work out whether it is a network problem or an application problem, which runs with the .NET framework. I must admit I have never seen this before. Additionally, I have never used ServerFault, I generally ask questions on Stack Overflow. I, myself, am a programmer, not a Server Administrator nor a Network Administrator. Hence my posting it here.

Comment: Start with a network capture to see what is going on on the wire.  Simplest place to start is at the server.  You should be able to see the SYNs being received, and then the SYN ACK reply from the server.  Now the question is, will the SYNs be retransmitted, indicating that SYN ACK is never received, or will just the SYN ACKs be retransmitted?  Based on the outcome, start moving your capture closer to the source to identify where it is going wrong.  Note matching SYNs is tricky because seq typically is normalized to 0; need to match with the raw sequence no.